# How to set SublimeLinter's pep8_ignore for project?

Tags: python, sublimetext, pep8, sublimelinter

I tried:

```
{
    "settings":
    {
        "SublimeLinter":
        {
            "pep8_ignore": ["W191"]
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried adding a "Python" level between SublimeLinter and pep8_ignore, but that doesn't seem to work. I can't find clear info on what exactly  is configurable on project level. I would expect everything that you can do on User and Default level, but cannot confirm.

Answer (score -1):

Your settings is wrong. Follow this instruction: 
Go to `Prefrences > Package Settings > SublimeLinter > Settings - User` and paste the below code into that file:

```
{
    "pep8": true,
    "pep8_ignore":["E501","W191"]
}
```

Comment: It will work for all projects, but I need exclude W191 only for one, I use spaces in other projects.